# LINQ get Max value from list

Tags: linq

I have the following table:

```
 ID Amt  Received
 -- ---- --------
 2  55   N 
 2  88   Y
 2  44   N
 3  5    N
 3  9    N
 4  5    N
 5  33   Y
 6  43   N
 7  54   N

    var result = (from rs in db.Exp
                  where rs.ID == id
                  && rs.Received == true
                  select rs).Max().Any();
```

Given an ID, I need to find the max Amt for a given id and then check if it is Y, if so, return true else return false.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should do it;

```
db.Exp.
    Where(x => x.ID == id).
    OrderByDescending(x => x.Amt).
    Take(1).
    Any(x => x.Received == "Y");
```

Comment: Nice. I suspect the last part should actually just be `x => x.Received`, but I do like the way this handles empty results.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson - I like the solution. I need to add another condition to the .Any(x => x.Received == "Y" && x => x.Division == "Accounting") but it not letting me do so. Any idea why. Note that Division is not in the above table. I forgot to include it

Comment: @NatePet You only need to include `x =>` once in a lambda, so it should be `.Any(x => x.Received == "Y" && x.Division == "Accounting")`

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately LINQ doesn't provide a "max by an attribute" method. [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) does with its `MaxBy` operator, but that can't be translated into SQL of course. So if this is a LINQ to SQL (or whatever) query, you'll need a different approach. If it's already LINQ to Objects, however:

```
return db.Exp.Where(rs => rs.ID == id)
             .MaxBy(rs => rs.Amt)
             .Received;
```

Note that this is doing what the *words* of your question ask:

- Out of the records with the given ID...
- Find the one with the highest amount...
- And check the value of `Received`

This is *not* the same as:

- Out of the records with the given ID where received is true...
- Find the one with the highest amount

Also note that this will throw an exception if there are *no* records with that ID.

If you want to do it in LINQ to SQL etc, you'd probably be best off with an ordering:

```
var highest = db.Exp.Where(rs => rs.ID == id)
                    .OrderByDescending(rs => rs.Amt)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
return highest != null && highest.Received;
```

You *don't* want to do this if you're using LINQ to Objects, as it will order all the results, when you only want to find the result with the highest amount.

Comment: @NatePet: You mean in a query expression? Which piece of code? Basically there isn't query expression support for `FirstOrDefault()` (and obviously not for `MaxBy`) so you'd have to put brackets round the query expression to call the methods at the end - and your projection would be a no-op. Basically it would be uglier. It's *definitely* worth being comfortable with both forms.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell it what you want the `Max` of.

```
var result = 
    (from rs in db.Exp 
    where rs.ID == id && rs.Received
    select rs)
   .Max(row => row.Amt) == Y;
```

And you don't need the `.Any()` at all

Answer (score 0):

```
// "I need to find the max Amt for a given id..."
var elementWithMaxAmount = 
    db.Exp
    .Where(x => x.ID == id)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount)
    .FirstOrDefault();

// "... and then check if it is Y"
var result = (elementWithMaxAmount != null && 
              elementWithMaxAmount.Received == "Y");
```